# What is the difference between resolve.plugins and plugins field in webpack configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

From *webpack* documentation I found, that plugins can be connected either with `plugins` field

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }),
  ],
  ...
};
```

or in `resolve.plugins`:

```
...
var DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");
 
resolve: {
  plugins: [
    new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
...
```

What is the difference between between these plugins, so they have to be connected differently?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between resolve.plugins and plugins is that the plugins configured in resolve.plugins work within the module's resolution rules. plugins are configured to extend webpack and are combined with loaders for maximum control

[resolve.plugins](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveplugins)

[Plugins](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/)